# "Select Extract Minute" failed in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

Please help me to solve this problem.

I need to extract minute from hour ("JAM" column) in a table .

I have try this query :

```
WITH recordabsen AS
     (SELECT userid,
          TO_CHAR(checktime,'MM/DD/YYYY')   AS tanggal ,
          MIN(TO_CHAR(checktime,'hh24:mi')) AS JAM
     FROM checkinout
     WHERE USERID = '688'
      AND (checktime BETWEEN to_date('04/01/2013','MM/DD/YYYY') AND to_date('05/01/2013','MM/DD/YYYY'))
      AND checktype = 'I'
     GROUP BY userid,
          TO_CHAR(checktime,'MM/DD/YYYY')
     )
SELECT EXTRACT (MINUTE FROM JAM) AS minute
FROM recordabsen
WHERE to_date(JAM,'hh24:mi') > TRUNC(to_date(JAM,'hh24:mi')) + 8/24
```

but returns an error :

Invalid Extract field

Comment: EXTRACT works on datetime or interval expression. JAM is character type in your query

Comment: @Ramblin'Man probably, although you're making an assumption - it's not uncommon to see people call `to_date` on a date column (which obviously is a bad idea)

Comment: @JeffreyKemp, actually he is not making an assumption, see in the WITH-clause: `TO_CHAR(checktime,'hh24:mi')) AS JAM`

Comment: ah righto, didn't even look at that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As soon as you've done:

```
to_char(checktime,'hh24:mi')
```

you got a string and not a date, so maybe it's better to use strings functions and not date functions, i.e.:

```
substr("JAM", 4)
```

[Here is a sqlfiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/18029)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just pass the checktime from the WITH clause query? Then, if checktime is a date, you can cast it to TIMESTAMP, which will allow you to use EXTRACT MINUTE:

```
SELECT EXTRACT (MINUTE FROM CAST(SYSDATE AS TIMESTAMP)) FROM dual;
```

Check at SQLFiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/18054